In floatingActionButton , I want full widht but there is some white space at right end of it. How can i remove white space
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
          width: size.width,
          child: customButton(title: "Next", ontap: () {})),
      body: Column(children:...mychilderns)
    );

And it shows something like this.
I have tried but I am expecting like this

Try to Wrap FloatingActionButton with Container and give width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.

"like this" are not shown!

You can use floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked instead.
Basically the FloatingActionButtonLocation predefined values refer to the X (center) and Y (docked) axis accordingly (for the centerDocked example). So with this in mind you can better use the offered combinations.
Also you can set any location you want by defining a custom offset like so:
class CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation extends FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    return Offset(
      scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width -
          scaffoldGeometry.floatingActionButtonSize.width,
      scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height -
          scaffoldGeometry.floatingActionButtonSize.height,
    );
  }
}

and use that as floatingActionButtonLocation value.

try giving width = double.infinity;

Sorry , but it's not working .
